# UIView rotation and movement

Tags: uiview, rotation

I try to rotate and move a UIImage.
Here is my code :

```
im = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 240, 100, 100)];
im.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[view addSubview:im];
NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30.0 target:self selector:@selector(actionIm) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void) actionIm
{
  [im setFrame:CGRectMake(im.frame.origin.x+1 , im.frame.origin.y+1 ,100, 100)];
  im.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (mRotation);
  mRotation+=0.1;
}
```

The result is a very strange behaviour : If I use only the rotation, it works. If I use only the move, it works. But both uses give a strange result (the IUImage "jump" bizzarly).

I red a lot of things about rotation, frame, bounds, center... but nothing that can solve my problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the center instead of changing the frame.  I believe setting the frame when the rotation is not Identity does something different.